# Confusion regarding connection form

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, connections

I have the following two notions of connection.

1. For a vector bundle we have a covariant derivative from sections of $E$ to sections of $E \otimes T^{*}M$ which is a $\mathbb C$-linear map and satisfies Leibniz rule.
2. We have a connection defined as splitting of vertical tangent vectors inside $TP$ where $P$ is a principal $G$ bundle [Here we care about $G=GL(n)$]

Now I have seen (and I believe I understand why) that by definition 1, a connection comes with a **local** 1-form and they **don't** glue but their exterior derivative (called curvature) gives a **global** 2-form.

But by definition 2, a splitting is just a $TP$-valued 1-form and since the vertical tangents at a point are isomorphic to $g$ (the Lie Algebra of $G$) we see that we get a $g$-valued 1-form.

> But this latter form seems to be a **global** Lie Algebra valued 1-form. Why is that so? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: By definition 2 you can see the connection 1-form as a Lie algebra valued **over $P$**. It is not a 1-form over $M$. The idea is that at each $p\in P$, the vertical tangent space $V_p P$ is isomorphic to $Lie(G)$, and being $Lie(G)$-valued, the connection 1-form gives projection onto the vertical space $V_p P$. The kernel of that  linear form is precisely the horizontal space $H_pP$.

Comment: Thanks. So regarding the **global** connection 1-form and subsequently the curvature 2-form : Does any of these descend to a **global** form on the base manifold?

Comment: I think in general they do not.  But there is a case in which the curvature descends: the curvature global 2-form (Lie(G)-valued) transforms under change of trivialization as $F' = g^{-1} F g$ by the adjoint action. If $G$ is Abelian, the adjoint action on $Lie(G)$ is trivial and thus $F' = F$: it agrees at all trivializations and descends. This happens for $G=U(1)$ (and $F$ is the electromagnetic tensor in physics).

Comment: However, if you want your objects to be defined over $M$ you can do one thing: forget about the curvature being $Lie(G)$ valued and allow it to take values in the adjoint bundle $ad(P)$. This is a vector bundle associated to $P$ and with this point of view you can write $F$ as a global 2-form over $M$, absorbing the gauge-indeterminacy in $F$ taking values in another bundle.

This confused me a lot not long ago, I hope someone writes a proper answer addressing these issues.

Comment: The property I am referring above is the following fact: there is a 1:1 correspondence between $Lie(G)$-valued $G$-equivariant horizontal forms on $P$ and $ad(P)$-valued differential forms on $M$.

Comment: You'll be surprised/pleased to hear that I was literally reading this exact same thing you pointed out right now from the expository article by Peter Gothen called "Surface Group Representations and Higgs Bundles".

Comment: He writes "F(A) is a tensorial form and hence descends to a adjoint bundle valued form on M". What is this **tensorial** thing?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment: I learned the definition of tensorial from Greg Naber's book "Geometry, Topology and Gauge Fields, Volume 2" (Section 4.5).

Let $P$ be a principal $G$-bundle over $M$, let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space (in our case it will be $Lie(G)$) endowed with $\rho$ a representation of $G$ (in our case, the adjoint representation $g\cdot \xi = ad(g)\xi$, or $g\xi g^{-1}$ for matrix Lie groups).

Let $\sigma$ be a $V$-valued differential k-form over $P$. It is said to be tensorial if it satisfies:

1. $g^* \sigma = g^{-1} \cdot \sigma$, where $g^*$ is the pullback of the diffeomorphism of $P$ given by the natural $G$-action. Here $g\cdot \sigma(V_1,\dots,V_k)$ is multiplication by the $\rho$-action in the target space $V$.
2. It must be horizontal, i.e. $\sigma(V_1,\dots,V_k)$ vanishes whenever **any** of the $V_i$ is a vertical vector.

One can show that $k$-forms over $P$ satisfying correspond 1:1 to forms **over the base $M$** with values in the associate vector bundle $P\times_\rho V$. In our case, the associated vector bundle is the adjoint bundle $ad(P)=P\times_{ad}Lie(G)$.